# Конвертация двумерного массива в ArrayList

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции, arraylist

Есть метод, который конвертирует двумерный массив в `ArrayList`:

```java
public List<Integer> toList (int[][] array) {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    for (int[] i : array) {
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(i));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Вызываю его:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConvertList convertList = new ConvertList();
    System.out.println("Массив: " + convertList.toList(new int[][]{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}));
}
```

Получаю в итоге:

```
Массив: [[I@1540e19d, [I@677327b6]
```

Объясните пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод `Arrays.asList(T... a)` принимает параметр вида `T... a`, что означает массив *объектов* типа `T`. Ошибка в том, что вы в голове подразумеваете под типом `T` в данном случае тип `int`, но `int` - это *примитив*, и он не может быть дженериком. Поэтому в качестве `T` понимается *объект* типа `int[]`

В итоге в вашем `list` лежит 2 элемента с типом `int[]`, выглядит это так:

> 1: [1,2]
>
> 2: [3,4]

Для исправления предлагаю 2 способа:

1. Заменить примитивный тип `int` на `Integer`

   ```
   System.out.println("Массив: " + toList(new Integer[][]{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}) 

   //........
   //........

   public List<Integer> toList (Integer[][] array) {
       List list = new ArrayList();
       for (Integer[] i : array) {
           list.addAll(Arrays.asList(i));
       }
       return list;
   }
   ```
2. Разворачивать внутренний массив руками

   ```
   public List<Integer> toList (int[][] array) {
       List list = new ArrayList();
       for (int[] i : array) {
           for(int j : i){
               list.add(j);
           }
       }
       return list;
   }
   ```

Да, собственно, если бы вы объявили переменную `List list` **правильно**, как `List<Integer> list`, то ваш код даже не скомпилировался бы, в вашем же случае есть всего лишь warning, на который стоило бы обратить внимание.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ) И первый, и второй вариант работают, но мне нужен именно второй вариант, так как "int[][] array", был условием в задаче.

Answer (score 0):

```java
int[][] arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

Собираем двумерный массив в лист:

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .flatMap(row -> Arrays.stream(row).boxed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Собираем двумерный массив в одномерный массив:

```java
int[] arr2 = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```